# oracle create same column name in different tables

Tags: oracle

i have two tables
Club (clubid, clubname)
Teacher (teacherid, clubid)

The clubid in table Teacher to tell which club he is in.
Problem is i get this error when creating table Teacher, after successfully creating table Club.

Error I get is:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"

Comment: you have probably have Teacher table in existing Db

Comment: Please give full error.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the column names. Columns don't have to be unique across tables. Look in the `user_tables` view to see that the table already exists, and `user_tab_columns` to see what columns it has - or `desc teacher` from SQL*Plus. You can also look in `user_objects` to see the `created` date which might help you piece together why it exists. If you're sure you created it - probably running this command earlier - then you can drop it and create it again... It's also possible you've added constraints to both tables with the same name, but you haven't shown that level of detail.

Comment: thank, just thought it realtes to column name, turn out I have a same table.